# Extjs History class and iframes

Tags: extjs, cross-browser, browser-history

Take the sample history example from Extjs framework. It works fine in Safari.
Now add the following lines to the history.html page

```
<iframe src='http://google.com'></iframe>
```

Now test the same example in Mac Safari. It just doesn't work. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem. For some reason my back button isn't controlling the hidden iframe.  It's updating the main URL in IE.